# Understanding prolog [lists]

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am to write a program that does this:

```
?- pLeap(2,5,X,Y).
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = 3,
Y = 4 ;
X = 4,
Y = 5 ;
X = 5,
Y = 5 ;
false.
```

(gives all pairs X,X+1 between 2 and 5, plus the special case at the end).

This is supposedly the solution. I don't really understand how it works, could anyone guide me through it?

```
pLeap(X,X,X,X).
pLeap(L,H,X,Y) :-
        L<H,
        X is L,
        Y is X+1.
pLeap(L,H,X,Y) :-
        L=<H,
        L1 is L+1,
        pLeap(L1,H,X,Y).
```

I'd do it simply like this:

```
pLeap(L,H,X,Y) :-
        X >= L,
        X =< H,
        Y is X+1.
```

Why doesn't it work (ignoring the special case at the end)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>=` and `=<` operators don't instantiate their arguments, and you can only use them once the arguments have already been instantiated.

Put another way, in the given solution, `X` and `Y` are given values with `is`, and the `<` and `=<` operators are only used on `L` and `H`, whose values are given by the user.  (On the given solution, try `pLeap(L,H,2,3)` and you'll get the same problem as you're having.)

In your case, though, you try to use `>=` and `=<` on `X`, which has no value yet, and so the interpreter complains.

Answer (score 4):

You could use library clpfd for you problem.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

pLeap(L,H,X,Y) :-
    X in L..H,
    Y #= min(H, X+1),
    label([X]).
```

Here is the output:

```
 ?- pLeap(2,5,X,Y).
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = 3,
Y = 4 ;
X = 4,
Y = 5 ;
X = 5,
Y = 5.
```